# Excel: How can I count and add number of FIND results?

Tags: excel

I have a few rows with a cell that contains text.

They are all formatted like so.

A1: My wife has 2 apples and I have 4 apples
A2: My dog likes 3 apples and I have 2 apples
A3: We have 1 apple

I would like to pass through each row / cell text with a "FIND" formula and return the total number of apples mentioned in the text, per line.

I have the following but it only matches the first instance of "apple".

```
=IFERROR(MID(B305,FIND("apple",B305,1)-7,1),"")
```

Please can anyone assist me on this (seemingly simple) question?

Comment: `FIND` can only return a single value.  To return multiple values, you could use helper columns, with each one using a start value for the previous instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"apple","")))/LEN("apple")
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]

***NOTE :*** `SUBSTITUTE` is a case sensitive function and will give incorrect result if `apple` is used as `Apple` in formula, as pointed out by @gms0ulman in comments. Hence following formula can be used instead.

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),UPPER("Apple"),"")))/LEN("Apple")
```

Comment: Caveat: case sensitive.

Comment: Interesting. I would have guessed he wanted the total number of apples, so would return `B1: 6`; `B2: 5`; `B3: 1`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Initially even I thought OP wants total count in column but his formula suggested that its just one cell.

Comment: I was looking at this line in his question *the total number of apples mentioned*.  I'll post an answer also and I guess he will clarify eventually.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I rather gave significance to *apples mentioned in the text, **per line***. But as you said only OP can clarify. Though +1 from me.

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking to count all apples in the cell and return the total number.  I will try your suggestions.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me if you want to return the number of times apple is mentioned, or the total number of apples in the line.

If you want the total number of apples in the line, then try this formula (note that we have to search for `apples` and `apple` separately).

First enter a Named Formula (`Formula --> Define Name`)

where

```
seq_99  Refers to   =IF(ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

Then you can use this formula:

```
C1: =SUM(IFERROR((TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))="apples")*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99-99,99)),0))+
SUM(IFERROR((TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))="apple")*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99-99,99)),0))
```

The formula is an **array-formula** so must be entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl + shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can fill down as far as needed.

The formula

- splits the sentence into an array
- compares each element in the array to "apple"
- if it matches, it will sum the preceding array element

[image]